# Coefficient of thermal expansion tensor

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-mechanics

This question pertains to the general coefficient of thermal expansion (CTE) tensor, with no assumption about isotropy. The CTE tensor is $\alpha_{ij}$. Is it possible for $\alpha_{ij}$ to be non-zero for $i \neq j$? Essentially this is asking if there is a such thing as a shear component of thermal strain?

Comment: You might be able to get more responses if you defined exactly what a CTE tensor is because I don't think that that's a very widely used concept. I and, I think, most people are only familiar with the thermal coefficient of expansion being represented by a scalar.

Comment: I did not define it because I do not know if CTE "tensor" is an actual thing. But if the CTE is a scalar then the material is isotropic. So for a material that is not isotropic, a single scalar should not be sufficient to represent the CTE?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404627/is-the-coefficient-of-thermal-expansion-a-symmetric-tensor See the answer in this link for somewhat of a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a 2nd order symmetric tensor (not necessarily isotropic), there are going to be 3 orthogonal principal directions.  But, for a set of orthogonal axes that don't coincide with the principal directions, there are going to be off-diagonal elements.  So, in short, there certainly can be shear components to the thermal strain.

Comment: Is there any difference between the terminology "orthogonal principal directions," "orthogonal axes," and "principal directions" for an ORTHOTROPIC material? I recall that the 3 orthogonal axes of an orthotropic material ARE the principal directions at which there's no shear?

Comment: That is my understanding too.